# Python: MySQLdb Installation Problems

Tags: python

Mysql version 5.0.77
Python version 2.5

#easy_install MySQL-python

When I try to install, I get the following errors:

```
_mysql.c:2331: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âopenâ
_mysql.c:2338: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconverterâ
_mysql.c:2345: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconnectionâ
_mysql.c:2352: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconnectionâ
_mysql.c:2359: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âconnectionâ
_mysql.c:2422: error: â_mysql_ResultObjectâ has no member named âconverterâ
_mysql.c:2422: error: initializer element is not constant
_mysql.c:2422: error: (near initialization for â_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offsetâ)
_mysql.c:2444: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âopenâ
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: good formatting is your friend.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.18-164.el5xen (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1

Answer (score 6):

`yum install mysql-devel`

Then,

`easy_install MySQL-python`